# Implementing a versioned repository

Tags: java, repository

I have an odd and possibly complicated question, that may be answered any number of ways. I am working on an autodidactic program that uses XML files to store data for lessons; these lessons may be created by anyone, but the general idea is to keep them stored in repositories where they may be accessed by anyone; however, I am not sure whether to roll my own repository, or if there is something out there I can adapt.

I like the idea of being able to track changes made to files and by whom. That being said, I feel I may be in over my head here. Can anyone recommend a tutorial on making repositories, or existing code I can reuse?

Comment: maybe this will help ? 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-content-repository-best

Comment: Intriguing. I'll take a closer look at the link later on.